# Can't enable Wifi programmatically on some devices

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Is it correct that this code won't properly working on absolutly any device?
Are there any ways to acheive it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean))

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and will have no effect. If apps are targeting an older SDK ( Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

Also make sure you have the requested the permission `Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`

Answer (score 0):

It should work for any device provided that the app manifest has the following permissions:

```
 <manifest>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
 </manifest>
```